# Google Messages: Contact names are not displayed

Tags: contacts, sms, android-12, google-messages, miui-13

Recently, I've found that Google Messages doesn't show a contact name for most of the messages. It's just a phone number displayed. When I click on Details, there is no contact information. When I go to contact via Contacts (Google) app then the number is here.

It doesn't show contact both on the phone and at https://messages.google.com.

The app has permission to allow Contacts.

App version: `messages.android_2022101_01_RC02.phone_dynamic`

Mobile OS: MIUI 13.0.15 / Android 12 SKQ1.210908.001

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the `messages.android_2022107_04_RC02.phone_dynamic` version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Uninstalled/reinstalled, did not fix.

Some contact did not have a 1 in front of the number - adding a 1 made them appear.

Even easier - I changed the current country from "automatically detected" to US in the messages settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It has already been fixed, over a year ago, the OP said it was software update